# Wordpress on localhost working, when sharing IP to connect receive err_connection_refused on .js and .css files

Tags: css, javascript, errors, local-installation

**What I have**: as title suggests I set up a WordPress installation on my local machine and can run it and visit it (Mac + MAMP) over `localhost:8888/myBlog`. It works fine. By sharing my IP I am able to reach the WordPress blog from another computer (`myIP:8888/myBlog`). But here is the problem.

**The problem**: the page loads, but not the .js, nor the .css. By inspecting the console I see six `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` for js and css files coming from wp-content (.css and .js of a theme I installed) and from wp-includes (again .css and .js files).

**What I tried**: I thought it was a problem of permission so I changed the main folder and all the files recursively with chmod -R 575 as suggested somewhere but the problem persists.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the URL for the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ? Is that still 'localhost', i.e. the other machines are trying to load the files from themselves not your server? Is the host, port and HTTP/HTTPS of those URLs correct? If they are, can you check the access and error logs of your web server?

Comment: Yes! It's still localhost!! I didn't realize that... how can I fix this?

Comment: That's the 'WordPress address' and 'Site address' in Settings, General. You should set these to the URL your clients should be using, i.e. probably `http://myIP:8888/myBlog`

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! If you answer I can upvote & set as correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, the problem was that the site address was set to `localhost:8888/myBlog`. This is the URL WordPress is expecting your clients to be using, and uses this to generate fully-qualified URLs for scripts and CSS etc. Hence your other clients were trying to load scripts and CSS from their own localhost.

The fix is to set the correct URL, `http://myIP:8888/myBlog`, as the 'WordPress Address' and 'Site Address' under Settings, General.